# How to deploy azure-appservice-samples/TomcatTemplate with JVM8

Tags: azure, tomcat, jvm

I have deployed "Apache Tomcat 8" template as a web app to Azure.
Everything is fine except the template uses JVM7 that is not suitable for me.
Geoserver needs Java 8.

The template is on the github:
https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/TomcatTemplate

I was looking through but i can't find any setup to change JVM version.
So how can I deploy this template but with java 8 ?

Update:
There are two kinds of template available. The first one that i mentioned allows to configure everything in tomcat like tomcat-users.xml. I am looking for this kind. The other kind only allows to upload something in the webapps folder and so you can't configure tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

How about this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-java-tomcat)? It specifically says Tomcat 8 and Java 8? Or you could utilize this part to specify Java version:

```
"resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                    "name": "web",
                    "type": "config",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "javaVersion": "1.8",
                        "javaContainer": "TOMCAT",
                        "javaContainerVersion": "8.0"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include that i need to configure tomcat also, i have tried the template you linked, but that not allows tomcat configuration. See my edit....

Comment: well, whats the problem, take just the javaversion from the template I linked. all you need to do is add `"javaVersion": "1.8",` to your template

Comment: No, i have created a fork from the original template, included the change and still JVM 7 ...

Comment: I'll test tomorrow, don't have time now, sorry